# Load Divi Library Component in Non Divi Page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the Divi theme on a WordPress site. I have saved some common components into the Divi Library.

Now I would like to show one of these saved library components on a non-Divi page but cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this.

I'm hoping I'll be able to do something like this:

```
echo get_divi_layout(MY_LAYOUT_ID);
```

Might be wishful thinking but if anyone has any pointers I'll be eternally grateful!

Answer (score 3):

Managed to get it working by adding the below in a bbpress template file:

```
$is_page_builder_used = et_pb_is_pagebuilder_used(get_the_ID());
echo do_shortcode('[et_pb_section global_module="28365"][/et_pb_section]');
```

Don't forget to update the global module post ID.

Hope it works for others.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this issue as well. divi.Space did release a plugin that allows you to use the Divi Builder on any page or post type and it works extremely well.

Here is a breakdown of the plugin: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/divi-plugin-highlight-page-builder-everywhere

And here is a link to the actual plugin: https://divi.space/product/page-builder-everywhere/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please be noted that unfortunately Divi doesn't support such action in a direct way. It doesn't allow you to use a library on a non-divi page. But, alternatively you can create a custom template file and call that file on your non-divi page.

On the template file, you can embed the code as mentioned by the user @A.M.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[et_pb_section global_module="xxxx"][/et_pb_section]'); ?>
```

To find the global_module value, go to WP Admin > Divi > Divi Library and look for the module that you want to embed and click on it to edit it. On the address bar, you would find the post value like "post=xxxx" and that's the number you would need to replace on the code above.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I would be more than happy to help you transfer your files from a divi site to an non divi site! I assume you have an Elegant Themes membership, so the first thing you want to do is is download the divi builder (not the theme, the plugin) from your ET dashboard. The next thing you need to do is add this plugin to your non-Divi website. Then you want to get the file with the layouts you need and export it. You can do this by going to the Divi Library and selecting the files you want to export. After you are done with this click "Import & Export" (at the top) and then make sure it is on export. Select "Only export selected items" and then click "Export Divi Builder Layouts"

Now, go to the sidebar of wp-admin on your nondivi theme site, and find Divi. Hover over this, and click "Divi Libray". Now, click "Import & Export" (at the top of the page), and then click "Import". Import the file, click "Import Divi Builder Layouts" (if it says it doesn't like the file type just upload it again, and it should work), and then go to the page where you need this layout. Click "Use the Divi Builder". Next, click "Load from Libray", and then "Add from Libray", and find your file. Now click "Load".  You can now test out your page and see how it looks.  I hope this helps!